# .NET 5 Alternative for MaintainScrollPosition in previous versions?

Tags: asp.net, blazor, .net-5, asp.net-blazor

I'd like to use something like this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback?view=netframework-4.8

to save scroll position on the browser navigating back but it looks like it doesn't apply to .NET 5. This is for a blazor server side project, is there a way to do this without using some JavaScript?

Comment: Not specifically a replacement but it's possible to call the browser API to manage scroll positions, Steve did a Demo at NDC Manchester last week which uses this: https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/presentation-2021-01-NDCLondon/blob/master/demo/CalendarApp/src/CalendarApp/wwwroot/scroller.js

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think so.  However, the Javascript for doing this is so trivial that I wouldn't mind using Interop for it.